# Refer to specific cell in xslt import/export filter for Calc

Tags: xslt, filter, openoffice-calc

I am using xslt filter for importing/exporting data from Calc worksheet. Is it possible to refer to a specific cell address ? For example, if we want to export data from cell B2, how do we refer to this cell address in export xslt ?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post an openoffice xml sample as well as the xslt that you have so far? Not many people are familiar with openoffice xml but a lot of people are familiar with xslt and may not have to know that much about openoffice to help you

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about Openoffice or their xslt filter function, I can tell you that you're probably going to need a fairly simple XPath to reference a specific Cell's data - I doubt it would be as simple as calling `getCell('B2')` unless they have provided you with some custom xslt functions (I'm assuming they've put you in a raw XSLT environment).

Anyway, I think this question *may* be more about XSLT and xpath, than it is about openoffice. With that in mind, I'm going to fashion my own sample xml and examples and hopefully that will be enough to get you started.

For an input xml that looks something like this:

```
<ooo_calc_export>
    <ooo_sheet num="1" name="sheet1">
        <ooo_row num="2">
            <fisrtCell>Oh</firstCell>
            <secondCell>Hai</secondCell>
            <thirdCell>There</thirdCell>
        </ooo_row>
        <ooo_row num="3">
            <fisrtCell>Oh</firstCell>
            <secondCell>Hello</secondCell>
            <thirdCell>Back!</thirdCell>
        </ooo_row>
    </ooo_sheet>
</ooo_calc_export>
```

An absolute XPath to access cell B2's data would look like this `ooo_calc_export/ooo_sheet/ooo_row[@num='2']/secondCell/text()`

But the above is an absolute path and in XSLT, we would often author relative xpaths as we are in the midst of processing a document. Imagine you're in a template which matches on the `ooo_calc_export` node and you wanted to store Cell B2's data in a variable for later use. Consider this example:

```
<xsl:template match="/ooo_calc_export">

    <!-- a relative xpath does not being with a forward slash -->
    <xsl:variable name="B2" select="ooo_sheet/ooo_row[@num='2']/secondCell/text()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Now lets imagine you wanted a template to match on the cell B2 node itself:

```
<xsl:template match="ooo_row[@num='2']/secondCell">

    <!-- a relative xpath does not being with a forward slash -->
    <xsl:variable name="B2_text" select="text()" />

</xsl:template>
```

This is a [good tutorial on XSLT](http://www.vogella.com/articles/XSLT/article.html) to get you started. Also, the W3 Schools references on [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) and [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) aren't the worst.